# Adding certain values of a XML feed together then output

Tags: php, curl

Hi wonder if anyone could help me.

the first code below basically counted every XML record and outputted in a desired formatt

Old code

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://xxxxx');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$xml_string = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

// parse data
$xml=simplexml_load_string($xml_string);

// fix to n slots, zero padded
$slots=6;
$counter = substr((string)(pow(10,$slots)+count($xml)),1,$slots);

for($c=0; $c<strlen($counter); $c++)
{
    echo("<span>".$counter[$c]."</span>");
}
```

Out put

```
<span>1</span><span>3</span><span>5</span><span>6</span><span>8</span><span>8</span>
```

this was all ok but now the XML feed has changed and is just outputting the below.

```
<Data>
    <Row>
        <Column name="cam" type="xs:int">000</Column>
        <Column name="camN" type="xs:string">hello</Column>
        <Column name="numer" type="xs:int">1</Column>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Column name="cam" type="xs:int">000</Column>
        <Column name="camN" type="xs:string">hello</Column>
        <Column name="numer" type="xs:int">985</Column>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Column name="cam" type="xs:int">000</Column>
        <Column name="camN" type="xs:string">hello</Column>
        <Column name="numer" type="xs:int">1</Column>
    </Row>      
</Data>
```

i need the same output to happen but not sure how i take the number value from each record + them togther and then output them making sure i have 6 charactures even if it ends up 000005 as a value

Cheers

Update

---

sorry i need to add the numer values together to get a totel so if the totel is 987 i need it to output:

`<span>0</span><span>0</span><span>0</span><span>9</span><span>8</span><span>7</span>`

Comment: I don't understand the desired output. Which values on the new XML should be summed?

Comment: sorry updated my post sorry missed that bit off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use xpath to grab the nodes you want, like so:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string( $xml);
$elements = $xml->xpath( "/Data/Row/Column[@name='numer']");
$sum = 0;
foreach( $elements as $el)
{
    $sum += $el[0];
}
echo $sum; // Prints 12660
```

Now, to get your desired output, pad the number with zeroes, split it into chunks of 1 character, and output it, like so:

```
$formatted = sprintf('%06d', $sum);
echo '<span>' . implode( '</span><span>', str_split( $formatted)) . '</span>';
```

Comment: thank you how do i always make sure its 6 charactures even if the value is 400 i need it to output 000400 with spans round ea value like above.

Comment: The call to sprintf will take care of that `:)` - That's why it has `%06d`, this means to format the number to a decimal value of width 6, and to pad the number with zeros if it's not 6 digits.

Comment: perfect thank you so much for your help on this, i have learnt something new today.... now it does export the 6 digits now but for some reason they are all 0 and they should be a value as i know the xml has values to add up, let me take a look at this one

Comment: sorted it (me being stupid) i would just like to offer a HUGE thanks to nickb and rdlowrey for the help on this, you have helped me alot... thank you again

Answer (score 2):

[SimpleXml](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) is the easiest way to do this. Given your supplied XML:

```
$xml = '
<Data>
    <Row>
        <Column name="cam" type="xs:int">000</Column>
        <Column name="camN" type="xs:string">hello</Column>
        <Column name="numer" type="xs:int">5220</Column>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Column name="cam" type="xs:int">000</Column>
        <Column name="camN" type="xs:string">hello</Column>
        <Column name="numer" type="xs:int">4220</Column>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Column name="cam" type="xs:int">000</Column>
        <Column name="camN" type="xs:string">hello</Column>
        <Column name="numer" type="xs:int">3220</Column>
    </Row>      
</Data>
';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$numer_sum = 0;

// sums the value of columns
foreach ($xml->Row as $row) {
  $numer_sum += (int)$row->Column[2];
}
```

Alternatively, you could use xpath to make sure you're always summing the Column elements with name="numer" even if the order of the xml columns changes:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);

// get only the column elements with name="numer"
$xpath_result = $xml->xpath('Row/Column[@name="numer"]');
$sum = 0;

foreach ($xpath_result as $numer) {
  $sum += (int)$numer[0];
}

echo $sum;
```

Comment: thank you for your reply i have asked a question re formatting below

Comment: Well, your question made it clear you had that part of the code under control. The change in XML didn't affect your ability to concatenate strings. I can't write your code for you and that's not what SO is for.